# Prove two points that might be essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

$f(z)=\frac{ze^{\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}}}{sin{\pi z}}$
I can find that $z=\mathbb Z$$-${0,1} are poles of order 1. And $z=0$ is a removable singularity. But how to judge the behavior of $f(z)$ at $z=1$ and $z=\infty$ ? I think they might be essential singularity due to the $e^z$ and $\sin{z}$ term. But how to prove them?

Answer (score 1):

At $z=1$ the $z/\sin(\pi z)$ part has a simple pole but the exponential part has a non-terminating Laurent expansion, so it is an essential singularity. 
As $z\rightarrow \infty$ there are more than one limit point on the Riemann sphere so it is not a finite order pole.

Answer (score 0):

What is $\lim_{z\to1}f(z)$? (And now what's the *definition* of "pole"?)

Comment: if $z=1$ is a pole then we have $\lim_{z\to1}f(z)=\infty$ but in this case, when $z \to \infty$ although the denominator is 0, the limit of numerator does not exist. So what can we get from that?

Comment: I missed part of the numerator. Yes, $1$ and $\infty$ are essential singularities. You can prove this by showing that they're not removable singularities and not poles. So you have to show that $\lim_{z\to1}f(z)$ does not exist, finite or infinite.

Comment: Yes, but how to prove this? This the most difficult point in this problem.